# How to make radiobuttons check themselves accordingly wth using a if else construction?

Tags: c#, radio-button

The following problem though I can not seem to solve by using google.

The program I am writing ask for an amount of shoes that are going to be purchased, then based on amount of shoes a discount is given, 0%, 15%, or 25%.

I have it all written so that the right price appears in a label, the only thing I need to do is make the according radiobutton check itself ( 0%, 15%, or 25%)

Can somebody tell me the syntax?

Code I have written thus far:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal schoenen1= 0;
    schoenen1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal prijs1 = schoenen1 * 100;
    decimal prijs2 = schoenen1 * 85;
    decimal prijs3 = schoenen1 * 75;

    if (schoenen1 >5)
    {
        label3.Text =  prijs3.ToString();
    }
    if (schoenen1 == 2)
    {
        label3.Text = prijs2.ToString();
    }
    if (schoenen1 >2)
    {
        label3.Text = prijs2.ToString();
    }
    if (schoenen1 == 1)
    {
        label3.Text = prijs1.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Set the Checked property of the RadioButton to true: `myRadioButton.Checked = true`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to assign the label only once, use if-else, otherwise e.g. when `schoenen1 = 6` then case > 5 and case > 2 will both be executed.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal schoenen1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal prijs1 = schoenen1 * 100;
    decimal prijs2 = schoenen1 * 85;
    decimal prijs3 = schoenen1 * 75;

    if (schoenen1 > 5) {
        label3.Text =  prijs3.ToString();
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    } else if (schoenen1 >= 2) {
        label3.Text = prijs2.ToString();
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
    } else if (schoenen1 == 1) {
        label3.Text = prijs1.ToString();
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Also, you can combine `schoenen1 == 2` and `schoenen1 > 2` into `schoenen1 >= 2`, since you are assigning the same value in both cases.

Alternatively, you can exit the method with `return`:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal schoenen1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal prijs1 = schoenen1 * 100;
    decimal prijs2 = schoenen1 * 85;
    decimal prijs3 = schoenen1 * 75;

    if (schoenen1 > 5) {
        label3.Text =  prijs3.ToString();
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
        return;
    }

    if (schoenen1 >= 2) {
        label3.Text = prijs2.ToString();
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
        return;
    }

    if (schoenen1 == 1) {
        label3.Text = prijs1.ToString();
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Yet another way is to use a switch statement:

```cs
switch (schoenen1)
{
    case > 5:
        label3.Text =  prijs3.ToString();
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
        break;
    case >= 2:
        label3.Text = prijs2.ToString();
        radioButton2.Checked = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        label3.Text = prijs1.ToString();
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
        break;
}
```

See also: [Selection statements - if, else and switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements)

Comment: hello.. i had already figured out how to make the radiobutton work.. while staring why price3 didnt function with the correct radiobutton i read your reply.. thank you. so if i understand correct when if would cause a "double response" else if, or return are the  2ways to prevent that? great help.. i will write it down in my C# manual i am making.... thanks a lot again.